# How to force `ls` to 64-bit sizes?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, ls, gnu-coreutils

`ls` will, as far as I can tell, only write out file sizes as 32-bit ints. This has caused problems for me when I have a 5.4GB files that it insists are only 1.6GB. I'm on GNU coreutils version 5.97 and it's becoming a problem. Is there a compilation flag or otherwise command-line option to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.97 is 10 years old now, but it should have been using AC_SYS_LARGEFILE back then. What system is this?

Comment: MinGW (msys? Not actually sure what part of the system it is). But it insists this is up to date. Damn.

Comment: I see mingw support has changed quite a bit since 5.97. My suggestion would be to use the latest version 8.25-2 which is available for cygwin